# How do I use fetch_feed() to pull in a large number of posts?

Tags: rss, feed

When I use fetch_feed() to pull in posts from a feed, even if I set the maximum posts variable to a very high number, it will only pull in 10 posts. I want to pull in all the posts and then paginate the way I would for my regular blog posts. I thought maybe it was set to the number in my Reading settings, but I changed it to 30 with no change. There are definitely more than 10 posts in the feed I am trying to pull in. Is this possible or is this inherently limited for this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your source feed is showing only 10 posts. So, regardless of what you pit for get_item_quantity, only 10 posts will show, max.

If you're pulling posts from a WordPress site, you can adjust how many posts are included in the RSS feed in Settings -> Reading.

Change this value: "Syndication feeds show the most recent"

Answer (score 3):

If someone happens upon this and doesn't have the option to change the feed length, my solve was to use an array of feed pages:

```
fetch_feed( array('http://example.com/feed/', 'http://example.com/feed/?paged=2', 'http://example.com/feed/?paged=3') );
```

Answer (score 1):

from wordpress codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

```
    // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5. 
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5); 

// Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
```

change the $maxitems to whatever you want. hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you, but I should have been more clear. What I meant by "even if I set the maximum posts variable to a very high number, it will only pull in 10 posts" was that I changed `maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5);`  to `maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(99);` This didn't change the number of posts.